# Grails: Make default Text for select dropdown non-selectable

Tags: grails, select, default

I am populating a select dropdown from MongoDB database and then clicking on submit to perform some action on the selected value. I want to show default text for my select dropdown but also want that the default option should not allow to click submit unless some other value is chosen.

I tried this:

```
<g:select name="websiteSelection"
                            from="${websitesList.website}" id="mySelect"  noSelection="${['null':'Select Website']}"
                            class="styled-select" value="select" />
```

But this allows me to press submit when nothing is selected apart from default text. Is there any way I can achieve this requirement?

Comment: You can use the html5 validation by adding required="required". But that will only work on html5 enabled browsers.

Comment: Oh is there any other way? I basically want to show default text but dont want to submit the form when that default text is selected

Comment: Add in some jquery that would prevent the form submission when that element contains the default/noSeleection value.

Comment: Oh I dont know JQuery. Thanks will learn and implement :)